# Validation expression

Tags: validation, expression

I'm using prontoforms to create a simple app and I need an expression to validate a project number. The numberwould be in the format T000-0000 or T000-TT00. I.e A capital letter followed by 3 digits followed by a hyphen followed by (a) 4 digits or (b) 2 letters and 2 digits

Comment: Supposing you're talking about a regular expression, you can try this: `([A-Z]{1}\d{3}\-\d{4}|[A-Z]{1}\d{3}\-[A-Z]{2}\d{2})`. Anyways, maybe you could try to be more specific in the next time you make a question, ok?

Comment: Thanks, my apologies I don't really know much about this subject. I'll try that.

Comment: It worked. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome! If you think it's worth please, mark my answer clicking on the triangle above the flag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
/((\w){1}(\d){3})-((((\d){2})|(\w){2})(\d){2})/m
```

Now you must use the RegExp testing method of your language.